# The Entity type is not part of the model for the current context Multiple calls

Tags: c#, sql, entity

I have an app that calls two separate c# projects. Both projects use the entity framework and work fine independently. However if i open one app straight after the other i get the error: "The entity type is not part of the model for the current context".

I've attached a screenshot to show the error i get when i call one app after another. 
I've also attached a screenshot of when i call the app first and it works fine.[image: Works]

[image]

Also, I am disposing of the disposing dbContext with the .Dispose() method.

Comment: Does **mLookupType** exist in both projects? It might be a name clash.

Comment: No, doesn't exist in both projects. In fact neither project share any tables.

Comment: Ok, could you please be more precise on what you mean by **i open one app straight after the other**

Comment: Sure, I have a legacy application LX. I have two c# entity frame work projects E1 and E2. Open LX open E1 works. Restart LX open E2 that works. Restart LX open E1 works, close E1 open E2 get error. Restart LX open E2, works, close E2, try open E1, error.

Comment: Basically, if i restart the legacy app in between opening the entity frame work projects it works fine. but i if i don't restart the legacy app i get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! 
The problem was both projects were using the same name for the DBContext. I renamed that in one of the projects and the problem went away. I'm guessing the config file was getting created and not getting deleted when the app closed. Then the second app came along, seen the file and used it. But it didn't have the right table names.
Thanks for the help guys.